# Unable to play streaming audio

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to play streaming audio on an iOS app. I use this code to play audio:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://online.radiorecord.ru:8102/chil_320.m3u")!
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
player.play()
```

When I run the app on the Simulator I get this error:

```
2018-11-30 21:57:26.097577+0300 radio[7417:21800733]
[AudioHAL_Client]    
AudioHardware.cpp:1210:AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener:  
AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener: no object with given ID 0
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score -3):

```
var player: AVPlayer?
let url = URL(string: "http://online.radiorecord.ru:8102/chil_320.m3u")!
player = AVPlayer(url: url)

player?.play()
```

Comment: I do not want to know a song duration. I need to play streaming audio.

Comment: you mean live stream?

Comment: Avoid posting code without proper instructions and comments about what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I mean live stream.